# How to send an E-mail with AWK using the SYSTEM command

Tags: bash, email, awk

So I have this uni homework where I need to send an E-mail to all the people from a certain group of students (which are listed in the diak.lst file) and to attach the text from a file to the mail as well. The address of the students is in a similar form: xy9999, 2 characters and 4 numbers.
The problem seems to be at the SYSTEM part, it says that there is no such thing as "attachedfile".

The diak.lst is in the following format:

> *F-Name,Name,Address,Group*
>   George Peter gp9999 511

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f $2 ] 
    then echo $2 Not a file!!
    exit 1
fi
awk -v group=$1 -v attachedfile=$2 'BEGIN {fs=" ";nr_sent_to=0;}
{
        if ($4==group){

    system("mail -s \"Attention!\"" $3 " < " attachedfile);
    nr_sent_to++;
    } 
}
END {
print nr_sent_to,"-have received the mail";
}
' diak.lst
```

Comment: You have attachedfile in quotes. So it will look for a file called `attachedfile` and not the file in the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one problem got solved and others appeared, currently I get this error message: Send options without primary recipient specified. UsagE:mail -eiIudEfntBDNHRVv~ -T FILE -u User......... and specifies every possible option of how to use it. Note that this homework is dont at home and currently I am not linked to the server so any error which says that address is not valid should not be considered

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a space before $3 in the string `mail` sees- try changing `\"Attention!\"" $3` to `\"Attention!\" " $3`.

You have `fs=" "` which does nothing. Maybe you mean `FS=" "` but that's the default value so it will do nothing.

Your input file has a comma-separated header line so when processing that $3 etc. will be blank, add a `NR>1` clause.

awk vars already init to 0/NULL so no need for `nr_sent_to=0`. You do have to then add `+0` when printing it in the END section to make sure the number zero instead of the NULL string is printed if/when no emails are sent.

Given that everything you are doing in the BEGIN section is doing nothing useful, get rid of the BEGIN section.

Won't affect the script execution but: awk is not C - lose all the useless trailing semi-colons.

Put conditions in the condition part of the script, not the action part.

Quote your shell variables.

So with a bit more cleanup the end result would be:

```
awk -v group="$1" -v attachedfile="$2" '
NR>1 && ($4==group) {
    system("mail -s \"Attention!\" " $3 " < " attachedfile)
    nr_sent_to++
}
END {
    print nr_sent_to+0, "-have received the mail"
}
' diak.lst
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting the `+0` in the last statement to force `nr_sent_to` to be zero is the var has not been used before (no mail sent in this case). (Maybe that's not really important, but I feel it could complete this already very good answer)

Comment: Done. I was being lazy.

Comment: Do you not have to close the pipe if you use system and not getline ?

Comment: I don't believe so since system() returns the commands exit status so there'd be no point (if it was even possible) in system() when it returns leaving open a pipe to a command that had exited.